# Selenium Python: Unable to select combo value

Tags: python, selenium

I am accessing this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glz3f.png) and I have to pick one of Combo value that shows existing resume. I am getting error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Code I am trying is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/job-listing/developer-one-north-interactive-JV_IC1128808_KO0,9_KE10,31.htm?jl=1584069572')
select_box = driver.find_element_by_id('ExistingResume')
select_box.click();
select_box = Select(select_box)
sleep(5)
select_box.select_by_value(RESUME_TEXT_VALUE)
```

*Updated* The required element is right there

[image]

**Update #2**: Checked that element is not visible in static html. Guess via JS being loaded.

**Update #3**: OK I made following changes which prints tag name that is `select`:

```
select_box = driver.find_element_by_id('ExistingResume')
print(select_box.tag_name)
```

Now mission is to select the value from that combo

Comment: Because there's no element called `ExistingResume`...I can only find one called `ExistingResumeCount`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Check Update#3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Keys.ARROW_DOWN` to get the option and `Keys.RETURN` to select. See below:

```
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("ExistingResumeSelectBoxIt").click()
>>> d = driver.find_element_by_id("ExistingResumeSelectBoxIt")
>>> d.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
>>> d.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("ExistingResumeSelectBoxIt").text
u'mesut gunes resume eng.pdf'
```

You must be logged in and have a resume too.

Comment: `Keys` is unresolved. Which class need to be import?

Comment: did you import `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` ?

Comment: Worked like Charm!! What if have 3 Resumes in combo, do I need to send 3 Keys.Array_Down and then Return?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clean enough. The problems is that there is no element with id "ExistingResume" on the website.

If you open the console in your browser and type **$("#ExistingResume");** jQuery cannot find that element on the website neither.

Make sure you didn't make a typo in the id or you have all the necessary permissions to access that element. (Maybe it's visible only for logged in users.)

Comment: Isn't that element visible only for logged in users with right permission?

Comment: I guess so but I am logging first

Comment: Seems being loaded via JS

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to be logged in and have at least one existing uploaded resume.

---

You cannot directly control the `select` element with the resumes - it is invisible. Control the wrapping combo element that is visible.

Complete working code (including logging in):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/job-listing/developer-one-north-interactive-JV_IC1128808_KO0,9_KE10,31.htm?jl=1584069572')

# log in
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.actions span.signin").click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form.signInForm input.signin-email").send_keys("login")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form.signInForm input.signin-password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form.signInForm button.loginDlgSignInBtn").click()

# wait for the combo to appear
resume_name = "myResume.pdf"

# open up combo
combo = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ExistingResumeSelectBoxIt")))
combo.click()

# select resume
resume_item = combo.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-val = '%s']" % resume_name)
resume_item.click()
```

Comment: I am logged in and after trying your code I am getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@id='ExistingResumeSelectBoxItText' and @data-val =
```

Comment: @Volatil3 are you sure you are using an existing `resume_name`? Thanks.

Comment: It does exist. Now I am not sure it's doing exact match or ignoring spaces.

Comment: @Volatil3 okay, let me try reproduce the problem

Comment: @Volatil3 okay, updated with a complete working code to **select resume by name**.

Comment: Ok I found why was it not fetching earlier. My resume file name has spaces between text. Something like `My Awesome resume.pdf` which is set as `My_Awesome_resume.pdf` as `data-val` value. Now not sure it just replaces space with underscore. However by putting `_` sign it worked. The display-able name is set as `span`s `innerText` as original name